# GCM registration is not ready with auth credentials in ios9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Hi i am using GCM for push notification, it is working fine in `iOS8` but in `iOS9` it is giving error "GCM registration is not ready with auth credentials in `iOS9`" and could not connect to GCM: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.gcm error 501.)

Comment: I am getting a similar error:   GCM registration is not ready with auth credentials
Could not connect to GCM: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.gcm error 501.)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, after signing the app using a production certificate.

And the steps to make it work again are (this worked on 9.2 and 9.3 devices):

1. Put back `kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@YES` (production needs this to be NO)
2. Under "build settings/Code Signing/Code signing identity"  use the iPhone Distribution linked the GCM project (com.xxxx.yyy) and for Provisioning Profile, change back from Automatic to iOS Team Provisioning Profile:com.xxxx.yyy

Build, run, and wait a few minutes. For one of the tests, it took 15 minutes to register.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and as I understand, there are multiple possible reasons. But here is one that I have not found documented yet. And it is a nasty one.

To test a feature of our software, we were advancing our devices clocks. And we learned the hard way:

If your devices clock is off by too much, you will get "com.google.gcm error 501" form the GCM farmework.

Comment: Please explain devices clocks ? Any solutions for it ? Did it work afterwards ?

Comment: By "advancing our devices clocks" I mean, we set our iPhone clock to a time in the future. After setting the correct time again, it did work.