# Unable to get GCM token

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I got the following as my log, I followed the github sample totally.

```
2016-12-30 03:11:08.585: GCM | GCM library version 1.1.4
2016-12-30 03:11:08.669: GCM | GCM registration is not ready with auth credentials
Could not connect to GCM: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.gcm error 501.)
af442b82bffdf3bc1c1a30189be3edd77c9fe73e0b486b1fad58bdb535a1ea85
2016-12-30 03:11:25.255376 WeddingLah[6326:1609423] XPC connection interrupted
Registration to GCM failed with error: Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.iid error 0.)")
af442b82bffdf3bc1c1a30189be3edd77c9fe73e0b486b1fad58bdb535a1ea85
Registration to GCM failed with error: Optional("The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.iid error 0.)")
```

Things I tried:
Regenerate cert

Manually specify dev team and profile

sanboxOption = true

Anyone has any idea?

I included my device token in my log to show I did register my notifications properly.

Comment: try to use FCM, its much easier and fresh

Comment: I understand that. But unfortunately this is a freelance client project hence I don't have a say about FCM or GCM

Comment: Does this help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087706/gcm-registration-is-not-ready-with-auth-credentials-in-ios9 ?

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/205

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @GAEfan's recommended links, this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375229/ios-gcm-error-code-501) stated that maybe you are calling

```
GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler() { error in  if(error != nil) {   print(error) } }
```

before you had received a registration token, or had failed to refresh your token. Try [refreshing your registration token](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client#handle-refreshed-tokens) and see if it works.

You may also check this related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918922/proper-sequence-to-get-registration-token-for-gcm-push-notification-on-ios-is-g).